# Net money invested in Stock indexes ended up in red

Tags: stocks, india, financial-literacy, stock-exchanges

A look at the Indian Stock exchange trade today [here](http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/categorywise_turnover.aspx?expandable=3) shows a net investment of INR 296 crores but all the indices Nifty (-38.2), BSE (-137.30) ended in red. Why so?

When money is pumped into the markets the indices should be green?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got the 296 crores figure. The data on the sheet shows activity by category of investors. In the end NET of all BUY and SELL across all categories will always be Zero. It has no bearing on whether the stock market goes up or goes down.

If you compare only activity by certain category, say FII then there could be more SELL compared to BUY or vice-versa.